# Dual boot Win8/Linux on Asus Zenbook UX301 keeping intel imsm RAID0

Tags: linux, multi-boot, raid, mdadm, intel-matrix-storage

I have Asus Zenbook UX301 with Win8 preinstalled. I would like to have a Linux installed in dual-boot configuration. However, Windows is using the notebook 2 SSDs as intel RAID0 (rom-based RAID, fakeraid, imsm). I would like to keep that, as I like RAID0 and I would like to keep Win8 (I would have no way to reinstall it without purchasing new license if I break the RAID).
I enabled CMS in the bios and disabled secure boot.
When I boot into live USB (Ubuntu, same for Suse):
`sudo mdadm --assemble --scan -e imdm` and `sudo mdadm --examine /dev/md/imsm0` gives me:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/md/imsm0
/dev/md/imsm0:
      Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
    Version : 1.0.00
Orig Family : 27fcf6a0
     Family : 27fcf6a0
 Generation : 000063b5
 Attributes : All supported
       UUID : fa94a52c:a14df871:f7000c5f:ff62e7ce
   Checksum : 20064fe6 correct
MPB Sectors : 1
      Disks : 2
RAID Devices : 1

Disk01 Serial : 133622400063
      State : active
         Id : 00000001
Usable Size : 250065160 (119.24 GiB 128.03 GB)

[ASUS_OS]:
       UUID : 9a64aeb7:1788ce71:78eff01f:05bad5d5
 RAID Level : 0
    Members : 2
      Slots : [_U]
Failed disk : 0
  This Slot : 1
 Array Size : 500129792 (238.48 GiB 256.07 GB)
Per Dev Size : 250065160 (119.24 GiB 128.03 GB)
Sector Offset : 0
Num Stripes : 976816
Chunk Size : 128 KiB
   Reserved : 0
Migrate State : idle
  Map State : normal
Dirty State : clean

Disk00 Serial : 133622401167
      State : active failed
         Id : 00000000
Usable Size : 250065160 (119.24 GiB 128.03 GB)
```

which shows to me that one of the disks is failing. The only new device created is: `/dev/md/imsm0` which points to `/dev/md127`, while there are quite a lot of partitions on the RAID0 drive (at least 2 NTFS ones and win8 recoveries)
Chunk size is correct, but apparently something is wrong.
mdadm has a version of 3.3, downloading, compiling fresher version from the trunk does not help.
Additionally,

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --detail-platform -v -v -e imsm
mdmon: found Intel(R) SATA RAID controller at 0000:00:1f.2.
   Platform : Intel(R) Matrix Storage Manager
    Version : 12.7.0.1936
RAID Levels : raid0 raid1
Chunk Sizes : 4k 8k 16k 32k 64k 128k
2TB volumes : supported
  2TB disks : supported
  Max Disks : 6
Max Volumes : 2 per array, 4 per controller
I/O Controller : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2 (SATA)
mdmon: failed to determine port number for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0
mdmon: failed to enumerate ports on SATA controller at 0000:00:1f.2.
```

shows errors.

Attempt to use dmadmin (older tool) also failed.

Any suggestions?

PS.
I have read: 
 - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112527
 - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=176696

to no help